# Probability of truth in a chain of statements

Tags: probability

> Three individuals $A$,$B$ and $C$ tell the truth with probability $1/3$.
>
> (A) $C$ makes a statement and $A$ claims that it is true. What is the probability that the statement is true.
>
> (B) $C$ makes a statement and $A$ tells you that $B$ claims the statement is true. What is the probability that the statement is true.

Let $T_A$ be the event that $A$ tells the truth and similarly $T_B \ \& \ T_C$

My answer in the first case $\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}$.

---

I am confused with part $B$ of the question.

**My reasoning:** Probability of $C$ telling the truth is $1/3$. Now we don't know what $B$ said so we assume two cases. Therefore we would have the probability as $P(T_A \ T_B \ T_C \cup T_A \ T_B^C \ T_C^C) = \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{2}{3}$.

Is this correct? This problem appears as an exercise to Bayes theorem so I am confused as to how the theorem is applicable.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Assuming B actually said whether the statement is true or false, this looks reasonable to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful. We need to distinguish between "$X$ tells the truth" and "$X$ claims that $Y$ told the truth". The former always happens with probability $1/3$, while the latter depends on whether or not $Y$ is true or false. Let's revisit part (a) and redefine our events. Define:

- $X_C$: $C$ makes a true statement.
- $X_A$: $A$ claims that $C$ makes a true statement.

We're asked to find the probability that $C$ made a true statement, given that $A$ claims that $C$ made a true statement:
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X_C \mid X_A]
&= \frac{\Pr[X_CX_A]}{\Pr[X_A]} \\
&= \frac{\Pr[X_CX_A]}{\Pr[X_CX_A] + \Pr[\overline{X_C}X_A]} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1 \cdot 1}{9}}{\frac{1 \cdot 1}{9} + \frac{2 \cdot 2}{9}} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + 4} \\
&= \frac{1}{5}
\end{align*}

Can you see how to generalize this for part (b)?

---

EDIT: Here's part (b). Define:

- $X_C$: $C$ makes a true statement.
- $X_B$: $B$ claims that $C$ makes a true statement.
- $X_A$: $A$ claims that $B$ makes a true statement.

We're asked to find the probability that $C$ made a true statement, given that $A$ claims that $B$ made a true statement:
\begin{align*}
\Pr[X_C \mid X_A]
&= \frac{\Pr[X_CX_A]}{\Pr[X_A]} \\
&= \frac{\Pr[X_CX_BX_A] + \Pr[X_C\overline{X_B}X_A]}{\Pr[X_CX_BX_A] + \Pr[X_C\overline{X_B}X_A] + \Pr[\overline{X_C}X_BX_A] + \Pr[\overline{X_C} \, \overline{X_B}X_A]} \\
&= \frac{\frac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{27} + \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{27}}{\frac{1 \cdot 1 \cdot 1}{27} + \frac{1 \cdot 2 \cdot 2}{27} + \frac{2 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{27} + \frac{2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2}{27}} \\
&= \frac{1 + 4}{1 + 4 + 4 + 4} \\
&= \frac{5}{13}
\end{align*}

This diagram might help:

[image]

Comment: Could you give a hint for part b?

Comment: @Miz: I've edited in part (b).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Find the conditional probability that *the statement is true* given *the reports*, by establishing who must speak true or false for the report to make the statement true or false.

Let $T$ be "the statement is true *and* the reports were so spoken", and $F$ be "the statement is false *and* the reports were so spoken".  Find:

$$\mathsf P(T\mid (T\cup F))$$

$1)$ By what was spoken, the statement is true if both $A$ and $C$ spoke true, but it is false if both spoke false.   $T=A\cap C$ and $F = A^\complement\cap C^\complement$.

$$\mathsf P\big(T\mid T\cup F\big) ~{= \dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap C)}{\mathsf P\big((A\cap C)\cup(A^\complement\cap B^\complement)\big)}}$$

Answer (score 1):

We shall use a clear straightforward approach.  There are $2^3=8$ possibilities whether each of $A$, $B$, and $C$ tells the truth. We shall denote each of these possibilities by a triple of letters “T” and “F”, where a letter at the respective place indicates whether the respective person tell the truth. For instance, a triple TFT means that A and C tell the truth, whereas B lies. Assuming that each person says the truth with probability $1/3$ independently of that say (or said) the others, we obtain the following probabilities for triples (for the convenience we use a constant $c=1/27$):

- TTT – 1c
- TTF, TFT, FTT – 2c
- TFF, FTF, FFT – 4c
- FFF – 8c

It is easy to check the case when C makes a statement and A tells you that B claims the statement is true corresponds to (and only to) the triples TTT, TFF, FTF, FFT. Then by Bayes formula the probability that the statement is true is

$$\frac{P(TTT)+P(FFT)}{P(TTT)+P(TFF)+ P(FTF)+P(FFT)}=\frac{1c+4c}{1c+4c+4c+4c}=\frac 5{13}.$$